# Which one is correct between the two sentences?

Tags: meaning, usage

Which one is correct between the two sentences? What to do? or what is to be done? To my thinking, both sentences seem to be correct.

Comment: What is to be done is the title of a pamphlet by V Lenin so clearly is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the situation, "what to do?" doesn't seem quite natural in conversations. Usually there's a subject in the sentence, for example: "what should we do?" and "what can we do?"

"What is to be done?" is grammatically correct, but it sounds too formal (or not used in casual conversations).